# python standard library - int

Tags: python, int

I was reading through the documentation to the Python Standard Library. In section 4.4. [Numeric Types](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex) there is a note to `int`:

> Conversion from floating point to integer may round or truncate as in
>   C

What does this mean? I thought int always returned the floor? Is that not the case?

```
>>> print(int(0.4))
0
>>> print(int(0.6))
0
```

Comment: no, it doesn't alway return the floor: `math.floor(-.5)` gives `-1.0`, while `int(-.5)` gives `0`

Comment: `>>> print(int(-0.4))
0` <- truncates, not the `floor`.

Comment: OK, so int works exactly like math.trunc(x) if x is a float? The documentation on built-in functions <http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int>, which I hadn't checked, does indeed state: "For floating point numbers, this truncates towards zero."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conversion from a float to a integer truncates towards 0 as it does in C. This is basically equivalent to `math.floor(abs(x))*sgn(x)`, where `sgn(x)` gives the sign of a number.